# How do I run a script that processes the contents of an s3 bucket?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am looking to process a group of images that are located within an s3 bucket. With the files located in a local folder, I can process all of the images in a folder at the same time. I want to use the s3 bucket as a folder, and process all of the images inside. I am using boto3 to access and manipulate buckets. Is there a way I can use boto3 to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use boto as a folder. You will need a service to fetch the images from the bucket, process what you want to process, and upload them back to the bucket.

It is very straightforward, AWS have several tutorials on the subject, like this one: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Comment: I am interested in perform a script, not a particular function on a whole group of images inside my bucket.

Comment: Regardless, you can't perform any kind of processing directly in the bucket, you have to do it outside, on some compute service, or even outside AWS.